# How to deserialize a json that contains a json array into an object that would contain a list?

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

```
{
"id" : "25",
"authors" : 
    [
        {
            "firstname":"Ayn",
            "lastname":"Rand"
        },
        {
            "firstname":"Mark",
            "lastname" : "Twain"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my Java class:

```
public class FavoriteAuthors {
    public String id;
    public List<Author> authors;

    public static class Author {
        public String firstname;
        public String lastname;
    }
}
```

- 

I have already tried using the following 2 approaches:

```
FavoriteAuthors favAuthors = Json.fromJson(json, FavoriteAuthors.class);
```

and

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
FavoriteAuthors favAuthors = objectMapper.readValue(json, FavoriteAuthors.class);
```

In both the approaches, I receive the following exception:

```
(no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Could anyone please point me to the right approach here?

Comment: Like the error message says, you need to declare constructors for the class (or setters for the fields) .

Comment: I think you need to define the List like below in the pojo class.

@SerializedName("authors")
@Expose
private List<Author> authors = null;

Else you also  check this link help you in convert online https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Stale question, the asker doesn't need the answer